Resizing picturebox programatically in vb.net
I am trying to resize a picturebox programmatically in vb.net.  I have a picture box with a width of 1080 and a height of 1920.  I want to keep the height the same and change the width to 608.  I  tried the following
Me.MELFI_Rack.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(608, 1080).   I expected this line of code to change the width of the picturebox to 608, but when I print out the width of the picturebox it still shows 1920.
How can I change the height and width of the pricutrbox programatically in vb.net
